# How does 12/30/9999 date in SQL work in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm reading a stored procedure and I noticed that the date parameter default is 12/30/9999 and also in the Where condition. How do this work in the stored proc?

In the parameter section..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [DW].[sp_PolicyDetail]
@InForceDate date = '12/30/9999', @PolicyEffectiveDateStart date = null, @PolicyEffectiveDateEnd date = null, @Underwriter_Full_Name varchar(100) = null, @Branch_Office_Name varchar(100) = null
```

In the Where condition..

```
WHERE P.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_CD= 'EXP'
 AND P.POLICY_STATUS_CD<> 'TMP'
        AND (   @InForceDate = '12/30/9999')
OR      (   P.POLICY_STATUS_CD= 'BND'
                 AND P.POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DT<= @InForceDate
                 AND P.POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT > @InForceDate
                 AND P.CANCELLATION_EFFECTIVE_DT > @InForceDate
                )
        )
    AND (@PolicyEffectiveDateStart IS NULL OR 
        (P.POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DT BETWEEN @PolicyEffectiveDateStart AND @PolicyEffectiveDateEnd))  
    AND P.FROM_DATE <= @InForceDate
    AND P.TO_DATE > @InForceDate
```

Comment: Whoever set up this stored procedure is using the date there to drive default behavior; if they pass in no date, it uses the default (which could be any date you're not likely to ever see) to force the WHERE clause to evaluate one way, and if they pass in a 'real' date, then the WHERE clause does something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server can convert strings to date by using the default server date format which would be MM/dd/YYYY in your case.

SQL Server can also convert strings of any valid format with `CAST` and `CONVERT` if you need, and provide the format